# spot checking ml models. How do i fit all models do i use a for loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am spot checking bunch of regression models.how do a fit multiple ml models, Would i use a for loop and do model.fit

```
#Variables 
alpha= [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
#function
def get_models(model=dict()):
    model['lr'] = LinearRegression()

    for values in alpha:
        model["Lasso"]=Lasso(alpha=values)
        model["Ridge"]=Ridge(alpha=values)

    model["Huber"]=HuberRegressor()
    model["Lars"]=Lars()
    model["Lasso_l"]=LassoLars()
    model["PA"]=PassiveAggressiveRegressor(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)
    model["RANSAC"]=RANSACRegressor()
    model["SGD"]=SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3) 
    model["theil"]=TheilSenRegressor()
    model["cart"] = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    model["extra"] = ExtraTreeRegressor()
    model["svml"] = SVR(kernel='linear')
    model["svmp"] = SVR(kernel='poly')
    #Loaded data and have X and y 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30)
#fitting models
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a for loop. I cannot see your problem?
by the way you are overwriting `"Lasso"` and `"Ridge"` models.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once your dict is filled with `get_models()`, you can fit the models with a `for` loop:

```
for model in models:
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop through several Scikit Learn models, and do all the fitting too.  Try the sample code below directly below and take at the links towards the bottom of my post.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier, LogisticRegression, \
    Perceptron, PassiveAggressiveClassifier

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier, NearestCentroid, RadiusNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel, DotProduct, Matern, StationaryKernelMixin, WhiteKernel
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from utilities import *
from universal_params import *


def gen_classification_data(n=None):
    """
    uses the iris data
    :return: x, y
    """

    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    x = iris.data
    y = iris.target

    if n:
        half = int(n/2)
        np.concatenate((x[:half], x[-half:]), 1), np.concatenate((y[:half], y[-half:]), 0)

    return x, y

linear_models_n_params = [
    (SGDClassifier,
     {'loss': ['hinge', 'log', 'modified_huber', 'squared_hinge'],
      'alpha': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.1],
      **penalty_12none
      }),

    (LogisticRegression,
     {**penalty_12, **max_iter, **tol, ** warm_start, **C,
      'solver': ['liblinear']
      }),

    (Perceptron,
     {**penalty_all, **alpha, **n_iter, **eta0, **warm_start
      }),

    (PassiveAggressiveClassifier,
     {**C, **n_iter, **warm_start,
      'loss': ['hinge', 'squared_hinge'],
      })
]

linear_models_n_params_small = linear_models_n_params

svm_models_n_params = [
    (SVC,
     {**C, **kernel, **degree, **gamma, **coef0, **shrinking, **tol, **max_iter_inf2}),

    (NuSVC,
     {**nu, **kernel, **degree, **gamma, **coef0, **shrinking, **tol
      }),

    (LinearSVC,
     { **C, **penalty_12, **tol, **max_iter,
       'loss': ['hinge', 'squared_hinge'],
       })
]

svm_models_n_params_small = [
    (SVC,
     {**kernel, **degree, **shrinking
      }),

    (NuSVC,
     {**nu_small, **kernel, **degree, **shrinking
      }),

    (LinearSVC,
     { **C_small,
       'penalty': ['l2'],
       'loss': ['hinge', 'squared_hinge'],
       })
]

neighbor_models_n_params = [

    (KMeans,
     {'algorithm': ['auto', 'full', 'elkan'],
      'init': ['k-means++', 'random']}),

    (KNeighborsClassifier,
     {**n_neighbors, **neighbor_algo, **neighbor_leaf_size, **neighbor_metric,
      'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
      'p': [1, 2]
      }),

    (NearestCentroid,
     {**neighbor_metric,
      'shrink_threshold': [1e-3, 1e-2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 2]
      }),

    (RadiusNeighborsClassifier,
     {**neighbor_radius, **neighbor_algo, **neighbor_leaf_size, **neighbor_metric,
      'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
      'p': [1, 2],
      'outlier_label': [-1]
      })
]

gaussianprocess_models_n_params = [
    (GaussianProcessClassifier,
     {**warm_start,
      'kernel': [RBF(), ConstantKernel(), DotProduct(), WhiteKernel()],
      'max_iter_predict': [500],
      'n_restarts_optimizer': [3],
      })
]

bayes_models_n_params = [
    (GaussianNB, {})
]

nn_models_n_params = [
    (MLPClassifier,
     { 'hidden_layer_sizes': [(16,), (64,), (100,), (32, 32)],
       'activation': ['identity', 'logistic', 'tanh', 'relu'],
       **alpha, **learning_rate, **tol, **warm_start,
       'batch_size': ['auto', 50],
       'max_iter': [1000],
       'early_stopping': [True, False],
       'epsilon': [1e-8, 1e-5]
       })
]

nn_models_n_params_small = [
    (MLPClassifier,
     { 'hidden_layer_sizes': [(64,), (32, 64)],
       'batch_size': ['auto', 50],
       'activation': ['identity', 'tanh', 'relu'],
       'max_iter': [500],
       'early_stopping': [True],
       **learning_rate_small
       })
]

tree_models_n_params = [

    (RandomForestClassifier,
     {'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
      **max_features, **n_estimators, **max_depth,
      **min_samples_split, **min_impurity_split, **warm_start, **min_samples_leaf,
      }),

    (DecisionTreeClassifier,
     {'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
      **max_features, **max_depth, **min_samples_split, **min_impurity_split, **min_samples_leaf
      }),

    (ExtraTreesClassifier,
     {**n_estimators, **max_features, **max_depth,
      **min_samples_split, **min_samples_leaf, **min_impurity_split, **warm_start,
      'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']})
]


tree_models_n_params_small = [

    (RandomForestClassifier,
     {**max_features_small, **n_estimators_small, **min_samples_split, **max_depth_small, **min_samples_leaf
      }),

    (DecisionTreeClassifier,
     {**max_features_small, **max_depth_small, **min_samples_split, **min_samples_leaf
      }),

    (ExtraTreesClassifier,
     {**n_estimators_small, **max_features_small, **max_depth_small,
      **min_samples_split, **min_samples_leaf})
]



def run_linear_models(x, y, small = True, normalize_x = True):
    return big_loop(linear_models_n_params_small if small else linear_models_n_params,
                    StandardScaler().fit_transform(x) if normalize_x else x, y, isClassification=True)

def run_svm_models(x, y, small = True, normalize_x = True):
    return big_loop(svm_models_n_params_small if small else svm_models_n_params,
                    StandardScaler().fit_transform(x) if normalize_x else x, y, isClassification=True)

def run_neighbor_models(x, y, normalize_x = True):
    return big_loop(neighbor_models_n_params,
                    StandardScaler().fit_transform(x) if normalize_x else x, y, isClassification=True)

def run_gaussian_models(x, y, normalize_x = True):
    return big_loop(gaussianprocess_models_n_params,
                    StandardScaler().fit_transform(x) if normalize_x else x, y, isClassification=True)

def run_nn_models(x, y, small = True, normalize_x = True):
    return big_loop(nn_models_n_params_small if small else nn_models_n_params,
                    StandardScaler().fit_transform(x) if normalize_x else x, y, isClassification=True)

def run_tree_models(x, y, small = True, normalize_x = True):
    return big_loop(tree_models_n_params_small if small else tree_models_n_params,
                    StandardScaler().fit_transform(x) if normalize_x else x, y, isClassification=True)

def run_all(x, y, small = True, normalize_x = True, n_jobs=cpu_count()-1):

    all_params = (linear_models_n_params_small if small else linear_models_n_params) + \
                 (nn_models_n_params_small if small else nn_models_n_params) + \
                 ([] if small else gaussianprocess_models_n_params) + \
                 neighbor_models_n_params + \
                 (svm_models_n_params_small if small else svm_models_n_params) + \
                 (tree_models_n_params_small if small else tree_models_n_params)

    return big_loop(all_params,
                    StandardScaler().fit_transform(x) if normalize_x else x, y,
                    isClassification=True, n_jobs=n_jobs)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    x, y = gen_classification_data()
    run_all(x, y, n_jobs=1)
```

Here are a couple examples that you can follow.

https://github.com/PyDataBlog/Python-for-Data-Science/blob/master/Tutorials/Yellow%20brick.ipynb

https://medium.com/vickdata/a-simple-guide-to-scikit-learn-pipelines-4ac0d974bdcf

https://machinelearningmastery.com/compare-machine-learning-algorithms-python-scikit-learn/